# Flush output after every line in output window with external build tool

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm wondering if it's possible to tell Visual Studio to print the output of an external build tool as it gets it.

I have an external build tool ([JSIL](http://jsil.org/)) called from my `.csproj` file like so:

```
...
    <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="$(JSIL) != 'building'">
        <Exec Command="JSILc.exe $(SolutionPath)" />
    </Target>
...
```

This works fine--the output goes to the Visual Studio output window. However, it seems that Visual Studio buffers the output of the command until it exits and then prints that output in its entirety all at once.

Since the JSIL compiler takes a relatively long time and has quite a bit of output, I would like for the output window to reflect that while building.

JSIL outputs commands by printing to `stdout` or `stderr`, but manually `.Flush()`ing these streams doesn't seem to affect the output window. **Is there some special API that I need to call to update Visual Studio about the progress of a custom build tool?**

Thanks!

Comment: did u find answer/solution to this issue?

Comment: I didn't, but I also didn't really spent much time looking into a solution. :/